# Why does my Backbone View button click event not fire

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I know this has been asked on here in some form but I didn't see any that matched my scenario really. I'm new to Backbone am still trying to get a handle on how to structure [my test app](http://jsfiddle.net/shlonny/KURPP/5/).

After reading [this](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/) I think I addressed the "DOM not ready issue" but maybe not Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in el on instantiation rather than setting it in the initialization function, it will work as expected.

```
var mainView = new MyApp.AppView({ el: $("body") });
```

Comment: That does work.  However, I was thinking that setting el in the initialize method would take care of having to supply el in the constructor.  Any idea why that's not the case in my scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can set the element as a property like so:

```
MyApp.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
    initialize: function() {
    },
    events: {
        "click #clickMe": "doWork"
    },

    doWork: function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert("Work Done!!!!");
    }

});
```